# C# How do I get collision recognized between two objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace SpaceInvadersV3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool isPressed;
    Shooter player;
    List<Missile> bullet;
    List<Enemy> pirate;
    Boundary bottom;
    Boundary top;
    Boundary left;
    Boundary right;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        player = new Shooter(450,460);
        bullet = new List<Missile>();
        pirate = new List<Enemy>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Enemy temp = new Enemy();
            pirate.Add(temp);         
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player.Move();
        foreach (Missile b in bullet)
        {
            b.Move();
        }

        foreach (Enemy p in pirate)
        {
            p.Move();
        }

        pictureBox1.Invalidate();

        if (IsColliding(player, pirate) == true) 
        {
            gameOver();
        }
    }
```

**Error** in `"pirate"` says that it cannot convert from `'System.Collections.Generic.List<SpaceInvadersV3.Enemy>'` to `'SpaceInvadersV3.Enemy'` I tried changing the `'IsColliding'` function below from `(Enemy b)` to `(List<Enemy> b)` but then it doesn't recognize `b.Bottom` and says that `List<Enemy>` does not contain a definition for Bottom.

```
    // Keybinds
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            player.goleft = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            player.goright = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            player.goup = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            player.godown = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            Missile temp = new Missile(player.x, player.y);
            bullet.Add(temp);
        }

    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            player.goleft = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            player.goright = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            player.goup = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            player.godown = false;
        }

    }
        // keybinds

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        player.Draw(e.Graphics);

        foreach (Missile b in bullet)
        {
            b.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }

        foreach (Enemy p in pirate)
        {
            p.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }
    }

    private bool IsColliding(Shooter a, Enemy b)
    {
        bool colliding = true; // presume collision
        if (a.Top() > b.Bottom())
        {
            colliding = false;
        }
        return colliding;
    }

    private void gameOver()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("you died");
    }
}
}
```

**Box.cs where both Enemy and Shooter classes inherit from**

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace SpaceInvadersV3
{
class Box
{
    public Image pic;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float speed;





    public Box()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        speed = 0;
    }
    // Image Resizing Code
    public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
    }
    // image resizing code


    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawImage(pic, x, y);
    }

    public float Width()
    {
        return pic.Width;
    }

    public float Height()
    {
        return pic.Height;
    }

    public float Left()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public float Right()
    {
        return x + Width();
    }

    public float Top()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public float Bottom()
    {
        return y + Height();
    }



}
}
```

I Don't think if Shooter and Enemy classes are really relevant, but if you need them, I'll post them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you learning to program or write games?  If games switch off of winforms and look at something like https://unity3d.com/

Comment: I'm doing an assignment for college.

Comment: I can't tell what your intent is but my guess is that you want it to check each pirate to see if it's colliding with the player.  If so, you need to move that check into your loop.  Right now you are trying to compare the player with a list of pirates and then still trying to use the list as if it's a single pirate.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yes, okay and how do I do that?

Comment: If you get the rectangles around your sprites, the rectangle class has built-in methods to detect intersections and contains etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (IsColliding(player, pirate) == true)
```

First of all, never write that. It looks amateurish to say "if **it is true** that these are colliding".  Say "if these things are colliding":

```
if (IsColliding(player, pirate))
```

Similarly, prefer `if (!whatever)` to `if (whatever == false)`.

Second, **please use plural nouns for collections**.  That should be `pirates`, not `pirate`.  You want to emphasize that there is a collection of them to the reader.

> Error in "pirate" says that it cannot convert from 'List' to 'Enemy'

Your `IsColliding` takes a shooter and an enemy, but you are giving it a shooter and a list of enemies.  `IsColliding` doesn't know how to deal with that.

**You already know how to fix it**.  You wanted to move every enemy so you wrote:

```
foreach (Enemy p in pirate)
{
    p.Move();
}
```

Now you want to check every enemy for collisions, so do the same thing:

```
foreach (Enemy p in pirate)
{
    if (IsColliding(player, p)) { ... }
}
```

An advanced technique that you will eventually learn is to use *query comprehensions* on sequences:

```
var collisions = from p in pirate 
                 where IsColliding(player, p) 
                 select p;
foreach (Enemy p in collisions)
{
  ... handle the collision...
}
```

But learn to walk before you try to run.

Comment: @AlcoGoblin: You're welcome. There is a larger lesson here: **some types exist to add a capability to other types**.  `List<int>` lets you do operations on *many* ints, not just one.  `Task<int>` lets you do operations on *ints you will know in the future*.  `Nullable<int>` let's you do operations on *ints that might be missing*.  Each one of these "amplifiers" adds new capabilities, but you've got to know how to get the ints back out before you can do math on them.